# Why isnt input function reading all lines from input txt file? Python

Tags: python, input

So I have a project, where my program reads a txt file and then converts the txt into a tab txt file ( basically it reads the input, and with the dicionary, when it finds a special character it inserts a tab '\t'). The program works fine (so far) but it only reads the first line until it finds a newline '\n', and I just cant understand what is wrong in my code for that to happen. Can someone indicate me where is my code failing?

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import codecs
from string import *


u'\xe1'.encode('utf-8')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Tentative 1')

file = open('Data Path', 'r+')

#sentence = file.read()
#sentence = sentence.decode('cp1252', 'strict')


with codecs.open('Data path', encoding='latin1') as f:
sentence = f.readline()


if u'\xe1' in sentence:
 print sentence

else:
 pass
#sentence = sentence.replace("u'\xe1'", "-")

def task():
 print '\n', sentence

def replace_all(text, dic):
 for i, j in dic.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
 return text
reps = {'^^':'\t', '(':'\t', ')':'\t', 'ISBN:':'\t', '--':'\t', '"':'\t', '.:':'\t', '|':'\t', 'p.':'\t', ',':' '}
txt = replace_all(sentence, reps)


def txt_conversor():
 txt = replace_all(sentence, reps)
 print '\n', txt

results = tk.Button(root, text='Results', width=25, command=task)
results.pack()
txt = tk.Button(root, text='Convert results', width=25, command=txt_conversor)
txt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I did tried to change f.readline() to f.readlines() but it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
_GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
exec cmd in globals, locals
File "C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\Script (Console Bug with conversor).py", line 6, in <module>
import sys
File "C:\Users\Joao\Desktop\Script (Console Bug with conversor).py", line 233, in replace_all
text = text.replace(i, j)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

So how do i read multiple lines from the txt file?

```
Input:
Correia, Teresa Pinto; Henriques, Virgínia; Julião, Rui Pedro^^ (2013)), IX Congresso da      Geografia Portuguesa – Geografia: Espaço, Natureza, Sociedade e Ciência--, ISBN: 978-972-99436-6-9, |Lisboa: Associação Portuguesa de Geógrafos. p. 977 e-Book 


Dominguez, L.; Aliste, J; Ibáñez Martinez; Natário, M.; Fernandes, Gonçalo Poeta (2013) – Estudio Socioeconomico de la Frontera entre Portugal y España, Edita Riet, Salamanca. (ISBN: 978-84-7797-403-1)
```

Output:

```
 Correia  Teresa Pinto; Henriques  Virgínia; Julião  Rui Pedro      2013          IX Congresso da Geografia Portuguesa  Geografia: Espaço  Natureza  Sociedade e Ciência        978-972-99436-6-9      Lisboa: Associação Portuguesa de Geógrafos.      977 e-Book
```

Comment: `sentence = f.readline()` *specifically reads only one line*. `readlines` is correct. You can't `replace` on a whole list, though - you need to apply that to *each item in the list*, separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.readline()` returns just the next line of the file up to and including the newline character, hence it it correctly stops after processing your first line.

`f.readlines()` returns a list of strings where each string corresponds to a line from the file. The problem in your case is that you are using a string method on a list object (`sentence`).

For fixing you can either use `read()`, which returns the whole content of the file as a string (and it's probably the most pythonic solution) or make sure to pass a list to your `replace_all` function (process list items one by one, use `.join()`, ect.).

Here you can find a nice explanation of the different file methods: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/Files/files.html#filemethods2a

Comment: Thanks @Railslide for the explanation and response! The f.read() actually worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use `f.read()` to get all text as one string (with all '\n' inside).

```
sentence = f.read()
```

Comment: The OP specifically mentions having used `readlines`, but had problems there too.

Comment: @furas The method f.read() did read all info, and it worked just fine, thanks!

Comment: @santoznma so you can mark one of answers as accepted, and if you have enough reputation you can upvote.

Comment: @furas done! just one thing, why is my question being downvoted?

Comment: Because it is too simple question. Answer is too obvious for us. We have a lot simple questions - it looks like people don't read documentations and tutorial, don't search existing answer on SO or in internet, don't try to find solution on your own but only wait for answer on SO.

Comment: for example: did you try to find in internet `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`, or read something about `list` or even use `print` to print all varaible to see what you get ?

Comment: @furas oh yeah actually I did, but the replace was not the cause of the problem, i knew it was the f.readline() and i didn't know why. If I recall correctly, SO gives an tutorial on how to write a question ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and as anyone can see, I did all it said and they dont mention: well dont ask because people think it's easy. Thankfully, user experiencied like you and jonrsharpe replyied for me :) I understand why you said it and why other users downvote it, just don't agree to downvote because one doesnt understand why something doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to read a file.

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    for i in file.readlines():
        print(i)
# end with (closes the file)
```